# How to check if one dictionary is a subset of another larger dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, subset

I'm trying to write a custom filter method that takes an arbitrary number of *kwargs* and returns a list containing the elements of a database-like list that contain those *kwargs*.

For example, suppose `d1 = {'a':'2', 'b':'3'}` and `d2` = the same thing. `d1 == d2` results in True. But suppose `d2` = the same thing plus a bunch of other things. My method needs to be able to tell if **d1 in d2**, but Python can't do that with dictionaries.

Context:

I have a Word class, and each object has properties like `word`, `definition`, `part_of_speech`, and so on. I want to be able to call a filter method on the main list of these words, like `Word.objects.filter(word='jump', part_of_speech='verb-intransitive')`. I can't figure out how to manage these keys and values at the same time. But this could have larger functionality outside this context for other people.

Comment: `my_dict == my_dict | subset_dict` on Python 3.9+ using the [dict union operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/).

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Convert to item pairs and check for containment.

```
all(item in superset.items() for item in subset.items())
```

Optimization is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: If the dict values are hashable, using viewitems() is the most optimizied way I can think of: `d1.viewitems() <= d2.viewitems()`.  Timeit runs showed over a 3x performance improvement.  If not hashable, even using `iteritems()` instead of `items()` leads to about a 1.2x improvement.  This was done using Python 2.7.

Comment: i don't think optimisation should be left to the reader - i'm worried people will actually use this without realising it's going to build a copy of superset.items() and iterate through it for every item in subset.

Comment: @Chad This is a much better answer, and does not actually require the items being hashable.  I have converted this to a [community wiki answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41579450).

Comment: With Python 3 `items()` will return lightweight views instead of copies. No further optimization is necessary.

Comment: What about nested directories?

Comment: this is hilarious. I'll leave the subject refinement of the humor to the reader.

Comment: @AndreasProfous for nested dictionaries, you need to recursively check all elements of the dictionary, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57675231/6651956 (it includes support for more than just recursive dictionaries, but you can leave that out if  you don't want or need it.)

Answer (score 217):

In Python 3, you can use `dict.items()` to get a set-like view of the dict items.  You can then use the `<=` operator to test if one view is a "subset" of the other:

```
d1.items() <= d2.items()
```

In Python 2.7, use the `dict.viewitems()` to do the same:

```
d1.viewitems() <= d2.viewitems()
```

In Python 2.6 and below you will need a different solution, such as using `all()`:

```
all(key in d2 and d2[key] == d1[key] for key in d1)
```

Comment: Caveat: if your program could potentially be used on Python 2.6 (or even below), the `d1.items() <= d2.items()` are actually comparing 2 lists of tuples, without particular order, so the final result will probably not reliable. For this reason, I switch to @blubberdiblub 's answer.

Comment: @RayLuo Yes, viewitems is not the same as items.  Edited to clarify.

Comment: `d1.items() <= d2.items()` is undefined behavior. It is not documented in the official docs and, most important, this is not tested: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e576f5aec1f8f23f07001e2eb3db9276851a4fc/Lib/test/test_dictviews.py#L146

So this is implementation dependent.

Comment: @RodrigoMartins It's documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views): "For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class [`collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set) are available"

Comment: @augurar you are right, I missed that. Though I still don't like how confusing this solution can be to any developer not aware of this behavior. Would go with defining a more explicit utility function like blubberdiblub proposed (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35416899/2468458).

Comment: @RodrigoMartins If you're worried about future maintainers, wrap the operation in a clearly-named function or add a code comment.  Lowering your code standards to the level of incompetent developers is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 44):

Note for people that need this for unit testing: there's also an `assertDictContainsSubset()` method in Python's `TestCase` class.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html?highlight=assertdictcontainssubset#unittest.TestCase.assertDictContainsSubset

It's however deprecated in 3.2, not sure why, maybe there's a replacement for it.

Comment: was curious, found this in [what's new in 3.2](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html):

*The assertDictContainsSubset() method was deprecated because it was misimplemented with the arguments in the wrong order. This created hard-to-debug optical illusions where tests like TestCase().assertDictContainsSubset({'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':1}) would fail.*

*(Contributed by Raymond Hettinger.)*

Comment: Wait, the left side is expected and the right side is actual... Shouldn't that fail? The only thing wrong with the function is that which one goes in which place is confusing?

Comment: @JamesHutchison [correct](https://bugs.python.org/issue13248#msg155797).

Answer (score 39):

For completeness, you can also do this:

```
def is_subdict(small, big):
    return dict(big, **small) == big
```

However, I make no claims whatsoever concerning speed (or lack thereof) or readability (or lack thereof).

Update: As pointed out by Boris' comment, this trick does not work if your small dict has non-string keys and you're using Python >= 3 (or in other words: in the face of arbitrarily typed keys, it only works in legacy Python 2.x).

If you are using **Python 3.9 or newer**, though, you can make it work both with non-string typed keys as well as get an even neater syntax.

Provided your code already has both dictionaries as variables, it's very concise to check for this inline:

```
if big | small == big:
    # do something
```

Otherwise, or if you prefer a reusable function as above, you can use this:

```
def is_subdict(small, big):
    return big | small == big
```

The working principle is the same as the first function, only this time around making use of the union operator that was extended to support dicts.

Comment: A side note: Other answers mentioning `small.viewitems() <= big.viewitems()` was promising, but with one caveat: if your program could also be used on Python 2.6 (or even below), the `d1.items() <= d2.items()` are actually comparing 2 lists of tuples, without particular order, so the final result will probably not reliable. For that reason, I switch to @blubberdiblub 's answer. Upvoted.

Comment: This is cool, but it doesn't seem to work with nested dictionaries.

Comment: @FrederikBaetens it's not meant to. Also, I believe there is no generally accepted way how to do that, because there are multiple ways you could go about it and there are multiple possible structures/restrictions you could impose on such dictionaries. Here are some questions that come to mind: How do you determine whether a deeper dictionary should be descended into? What about objects of a type that has `dict` as base class? What if it hasn't and still behaves like a `dict`? What if `small` and `big` contain values of different type at a matching key which still behave like dict?

Comment: Those are valid points, but a basic function that worked with plain nested dicts should be nice.

I posted an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57657881/6651956), but @NutCracker's solution is better

Comment: Sure, had it been a question about nested dictionaries (and had the exact requirements for the dictionaries be outlined), I might have had a crack at it.

The point is that a solution for nested dictionaries doesn't give the right answer when you want to know if a dict is a subdict of another in a flat way (i.e. when you want the answer strictly to be `False` when the values of the passed dicts are different for matching keys).

Or in other words: The solution for nested dicts is not necessarily a drop-in replacement depending on the use-case.

Comment: `{**big, **small} == big` would have worked too, didn't need to wait till 3.9 for this!

Comment: @ddejohn I wasn't even aware that's possible, that's really nice. In which version was this introduced? PEP 448 would suggest it was introduced in 3.5. Note also that this answer goes back to Python 2.7 when this didn't exist. Also, the union operator syntax on dicts in particular cannot be used before Python 3.9, so it still holds partly true.

Comment: I think you should put `big` as the first argument of your function, not `small`. Python's `unittest` module used to have a function `assertDictContainsSubset` that did exactly this, and it was removed because it was decided that [putting the small dictionary first is confusing](https://bugs.python.org/issue13248#msg155797).

Comment: @Boris as far as I'm concerned, the order is consistent with Python's builtins `isinstance` and `issubclass`

Comment: The function you're referring to (`DictContainsSubset`) has a reversed wording, so accordingly, there with that function the big one should come first. However, my function's wording is in accordance with the small one being first.

Comment: Though this solution seems quite concise and elegant, it has the drawback that it only checks for matching keys and not values. The solution using `d1.items() <= d2.items()` checks for both.

Comment: @LevRomanov It does check for values as well. Try my solutions with `d1 = {"foo": 123, "bar": 456}` and `d2 = {"bar": 789}` and you will see that `is_subdict(d2, d1)` and `d1 | d2 == d1` will both return `False` as they should.

Answer (score 27):

for keys and values check use: 
`set(d1.items()).issubset(set(d2.items()))`

if you need to check only keys:
        `set(d1).issubset(set(d2))`

Comment: The first expression won't work if any value in either of the dictionaries is not hashable.

Comment: The second example can be shortened slightly by removing the set(d2), as "issubset accepts any iterable". http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: This is wrong: `d1={'a':1,'b':2}; d2={'a':2,'b':1}` -> the second snippet will return `True`...

Comment: @FrancescoPasa The second snippet says explicitly: "if you need to check only keys". `{'a', 'b'}` is in fact a subset of `{'a', 'b'}` ;)

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> d1 = {'a':'2', 'b':'3'}
>>> d2 = {'a':'2', 'b':'3','c':'4'}
>>> all((k in d2 and d2[k]==v) for k,v in d1.iteritems())
True
```

context:

```
>>> d1 = {'a':'2', 'b':'3'}
>>> d2 = {'a':'2', 'b':'3','c':'4'}
>>> list(d1.iteritems())
[('a', '2'), ('b', '3')]
>>> [(k,v) for k,v in d1.iteritems()]
[('a', '2'), ('b', '3')]
>>> k,v = ('a','2')
>>> k
'a'
>>> v
'2'
>>> k in d2
True
>>> d2[k]
'2'
>>> k in d2 and d2[k]==v
True
>>> [(k in d2 and d2[k]==v) for k,v in d1.iteritems()]
[True, True]
>>> ((k in d2 and d2[k]==v) for k,v in d1.iteritems())
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x02A9D2B0>
>>> ((k in d2 and d2[k]==v) for k,v in d1.iteritems()).next()
True
>>> all((k in d2 and d2[k]==v) for k,v in d1.iteritems())
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution that also properly recurses into lists and sets contained within the dictionary. You can also use this for lists containing dicts etc...

```
def is_subset(subset, superset):
    if isinstance(subset, dict):
        return all(key in superset and is_subset(val, superset[key]) for key, val in subset.items())
    
    if isinstance(subset, list) or isinstance(subset, set):
        return all(any(is_subset(subitem, superitem) for superitem in superset) for subitem in subset)

    # assume that subset is a plain value if none of the above match
    return subset == superset
```

When using python 3.10, you can use python's new match statements to do the typechecking:

```
def is_subset(subset, superset):
    match subset:
        case dict(_): return all(key in superset and is_subset(val, superset[key]) for key, val in subset.items())
        case list(_) | set(_): return all(any(is_subset(subitem, superitem) for superitem in superset) for subitem in subset)
        # assume that subset is a plain value if none of the above match
        case _: return subset == superset
```

Comment: This fails for subset of  {"name" : "Girls"} and superset of  {"show": {"name": "Girls"}}

Comment: That's because it's not a subset. If we consider dicts to be searchable sets of (key value) tuples. Both sets have one element: One has the key value tuple "name":"Girls" and the other has the single element composed of a key value tuple  "show": {"name": "Girls"} and when two sets both have one element, those elements must be equal for the sets to be considered subsets of eachother. This is clearly not the case, they're both key value tuples, but one has the key name and the other has the key show, and one has the value Girls, and the other has a value in the form of another key value tuple.

Comment: Even with my definition of recursive subsets, which relaxes the requirement that "for every element in the subset there should be an element in the superset which is *equal to that element*", to "for every element in the subset there should be an element in the superset *of which that element is a subset*", your set isn't a subset because the level at which elements appear is important. Imagine family trees as dictionaries: {grandpa: {child1:{}, child2:{}}} shouldn't be a subset of {grandpa: {dad: {child1:{}, child2:{}}}}

Comment: Just an FYI, technically if 2 things are equivalent, then according to set theory, they are both subsets of each other. But in my own personal layman speak (and perhaps that of many others), equivalent things are not subsets of each other; that just doesn't make sense to me; they're equivalent. So, if you're like me you might want to check if they're equivalent as well.

Comment: Yes, you can replace equal with equivalent in the sentence I wrote above.

Answer (score 7):

With Python 3.9, this is what I use:

```
def dict_contains_dict(small: dict, big: dict):    
   return (big | small) == big
```

Comment: Please be more elaborative. OP did not explain very well.

counter-example (depending on interpretation): small = {'pl' : 'key1': {'key2': 'value2', 'otherkey'..}}, 2nd counter example small = {'pl' : 'key1': {'key2': {'value2', 'otherkey'..}}}

Comment: Can you elaborate on your counter-examples? What are the values of `small` and `big` exactly?

Comment: Sorry for late response. have a look at the examples in my dotfiles and alternatives https://github.com/matu3ba/dotfiles/blob/3d841489cbe5006627121e65d44a8401ca5f9c9b/templates/common.py#L327C1-L327C1.

Comment: In your comment you write:
`Example: big = {'pl' : 'key1': {'key2': 'value2'}}
Then small = {'pl' : 'key1': {'key2': 'value2'}, 'otherkey'..}`
But big has invalid syntax. 

Could you just give one counter example? I'm not saying there is none, I'm saying I don't understand where the approach is failing.

Comment: The approach is failing once you also want to match dicts within dicts, because Python does not follow inner entries of dictionaries (only the first level of keys+values) on default.     Test, if 'small' is subdict of 'big'
    Example: big = {'pl' : 'key1': {'key2': 'value2'}}
    Then small = {'pl' : 'key1': {'key2': 'value2'}, 'otherkey'..} matches,
    but small = {'pl' : 'key1': {'key2': 'value2', 'otherkey'..}}
    or small = {'pl' : 'key1': {'key2': {'value2', 'otherkey'..}}} not.

Answer (score 3):

My function for the same purpose, doing this recursively:

```
def dictMatch(patn, real):
    """does real dict match pattern?"""
    try:
        for pkey, pvalue in patn.iteritems():
            if type(pvalue) is dict:
                result = dictMatch(pvalue, real[pkey])
                assert result
            else:
                assert real[pkey] == pvalue
                result = True
    except (AssertionError, KeyError):
        result = False
    return result
```

In your example, `dictMatch(d1, d2)` should return True even if d2 has other stuff in it, plus it applies also to lower levels:

```
d1 = {'a':'2', 'b':{3: 'iii'}}
d2 = {'a':'2', 'b':{3: 'iii', 4: 'iv'},'c':'4'}

dictMatch(d1, d2)   # True
```

Notes:  There could be even better solution which avoids the `if type(pvalue) is dict` clause and applies to even wider range of cases (like lists of hashes etc).  Also recursion is not limited here so use at your own risk. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but here is my solution for checking if one nested dictionary is a part of another nested dictionary. The solution is recursive.

```
def compare_dicts(a, b):
    for key, value in a.items():
        if key in b:
            if isinstance(a[key], dict):
                if not compare_dicts(a[key], b[key]):
                    return False
            elif value != b[key]:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Aside of the name this looks like the cleanest solution. It is quite a pitty, that Python offers no libstd methods for these kind of standard things. I'd use `def has_fieldsvals(small: dict, big: dict) -> bool:`as method signature.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using `pydash`  there is `is_match` there which does exactly that:

```
import pydash

a = {1:2, 3:4, 5:{6:7}}
b = {3:4.0, 5:{6:8}}
c = {3:4.0, 5:{6:7}}

pydash.predicates.is_match(a, b) # False
pydash.predicates.is_match(a, c) # True
```

Answer (score 2):

This seemingly straightforward issue costs me a couple hours in research to find a 100% reliable solution, so I documented what I've found in this answer.

1. "Pythonic-ally" speaking, `small_dict <= big_dict` would be the most intuitive way, but too bad that it **won't work**. `{'a': 1} < {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` seemingly works in Python 2, but it is not reliable because the official documention explicitly calls it out. Go search "Outcomes other than equality are resolved consistently, but are not otherwise defined." in [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons). Not to mention, comparing 2 dicts in Python 3 results in a TypeError exception.
2. The second most-intuitive thing is `small.viewitems() <= big.viewitems()` for Python 2.7 only, and `small.items() <= big.items()` for Python 3. But there is one caveat: it is **potentially buggy**. If your program could potentially be used on Python <=2.6, its `d1.items() <= d2.items()` are actually comparing 2 lists of tuples, without particular order, so the final result will be unreliable and it becomes a nasty bug in your program. I am not keen to write yet another implementation for Python<=2.6, but I still don't feel comfortable that my code comes with a known bug (even if it is on an unsupported platform). So I abandon this approach.
3. I settle down with [@blubberdiblub 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35416899/728675) (Credit goes to him):

   `def is_subdict(small, big):
          return dict(big, **small) == big`

   It is worth pointing out that, this answer relies on the `==` behavior between dicts, which is clearly defined in official document, hence **should work in every Python version**. Go search:

   - "Dictionaries compare equal if and only if they have the same (key, value) pairs." is the last sentence in [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)
   - "Mappings (instances of dict) compare equal if and only if they have equal (key, value) pairs. Equality comparison of the keys and elements enforces reflexivity." in [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general recursive solution for the problem given:

```
import traceback
import unittest

def is_subset(superset, subset):
    for key, value in subset.items():
        if key not in superset:
            return False

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            if not is_subset(superset[key], value):
                return False

        elif isinstance(value, str):
            if value not in superset[key]:
                return False

        elif isinstance(value, list):
            if not set(value) <= set(superset[key]):
                return False
        elif isinstance(value, set):
            if not value <= superset[key]:
                return False

        else:
            if not value == superset[key]:
                return False

    return True


class Foo(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.dct = {
            'a': 'hello world',
            'b': 12345,
            'c': 1.2345,
            'd': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            'e': {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            'f': {
                'a': 'hello world',
                'b': 12345,
                'c': 1.2345,
                'd': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                'e': {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                'g': False,
                'h': None
            },
            'g': False,
            'h': None,
            'question': 'mcve',
            'metadata': {}
        }

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def check_true(self, superset, subset):
        return self.assertEqual(is_subset(superset, subset), True)

    def check_false(self, superset, subset):
        return self.assertEqual(is_subset(superset, subset), False)

    def test_simple_cases(self):
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'a': 'hello world'})
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'b': 12345})
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'c': 1.2345})
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'d': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'e': {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}})
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'f': {
            'a': 'hello world',
            'b': 12345,
            'c': 1.2345,
            'd': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            'e': {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        }})
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'g': False})
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'h': None})

    def test_tricky_cases(self):
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'a': 'hello'})
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'d': [1, 2, 3]})
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'e': {3, 4}})
        self.check_true(self.dct, {'f': {
            'a': 'hello world',
            'h': None
        }})
        self.check_false(
            self.dct, {'question': 'mcve', 'metadata': {'author': 'BPL'}})
        self.check_true(
            self.dct, {'question': 'mcve', 'metadata': {}})
        self.check_false(
            self.dct, {'question1': 'mcve', 'metadata': {}})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

NOTE: The original code would fail in certain cases, credits for the [fixing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49419880/3809375) goes to [@olivier-melançon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5079316/olivier-melan%C3%A7on)

Comment: code fails with a superset that has a dict nested inside a list, in the line `if not set(value) <= set(superset[key])`

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this:

```py
>>> d1 = {'a':'2', 'b':'3'}
>>> d2 = {'a':'2', 'b':'3','c':'4'}
>>> d3 = {'a':'1'}
>>> set(d1.items()).issubset(d2.items())
True
>>> set(d3.items()).issubset(d2.items())
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this wrapper object that provides partial comparison and nice diffs:

```py
class DictMatch(dict):
    """ Partial match of a dictionary to another one """
    def __eq__(self, other: dict):
        assert isinstance(other, dict)
        return all(other[name] == value for name, value in self.items())

actual_name = {'praenomen': 'Gaius', 'nomen': 'Julius', 'cognomen': 'Caesar'}
expected_name = DictMatch({'praenomen': 'Gaius'})  # partial match
assert expected_name == actual_name  # True
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers will not work if within dict there are some arrays of other dicts, here is a solution for this:

```
def d_eq(d, d1):
   if not isinstance(d, (dict, list)):
      return d == d1
   if isinstance(d, list):
      return all(d_eq(a, b) for a, b in zip(d, d1))
   return all(d.get(i) == d1[i] or d_eq(d.get(i), d1[i]) for i in d1)

def is_sub(d, d1):
  if isinstance(d, list):
     return any(is_sub(i, d1) for i in d)
  return d_eq(d, d1) or (isinstance(d, dict) and any(is_sub(b, d1) for b in d.values()))

print(is_sub(dct_1, dict_2))
```

Taken from [How to check if dict is subset of another complex dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64184040/how-to-check-if-dict-is-subset-of-another-complex-dict)

Answer (score 0):

This function works for non-hashable values. I also think that it is clear and easy to read.

```
def isSubDict(subDict,dictionary):
    for key in subDict.keys():
        if (not key in dictionary) or (not subDict[key] == dictionary[key]):
            return False
    return True

In [126]: isSubDict({1:2},{3:4})
Out[126]: False

In [127]: isSubDict({1:2},{1:2,3:4})
Out[127]: True

In [128]: isSubDict({1:{2:3}},{1:{2:3},3:4})
Out[128]: True

In [129]: isSubDict({1:{2:3}},{1:{2:4},3:4})
Out[129]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

A short recursive implementation that works for nested dictionaries:

```
def compare_dicts(a,b):
    if not a: return True
    if isinstance(a, dict):
        key, val = a.popitem()
        return isinstance(b, dict) and key in b and compare_dicts(val, b.pop(key)) and compare_dicts(a, b)
    return a == b
```

This will consume the a and b dicts. If anyone knows of a good way to avoid that without resorting to partially iterative solutions as in other answers, please tell me. I would need a way to split a dict into head and tail based on a key.

This code is more useful as a programming exercise, and probably is a lot slower than other solutions in here that mix recursion and iteration. [@Nutcracker's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52036129/6651956) is pretty good for nested dictionaries.

Comment: There's something missing in the code. It just descends down the first value starting in `a` (and any subsequent first value) `popitem` finds. It should also examine other items on the same level. I've got pairs of nested dicts where it returns the wrong answer. (hard to present a future-proof example here, as it relies on the order of `popitem`)

Comment: Thanks, should be fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
assert d1 == {k: v for (k,v) in d2.items() if k in d1}
```

This will give a clean error message from pytest, as it has built-in support for dictionary equality assertions.