# Check if a Dictionary is a Subset of another Dictionary with Key Value pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, set, subset

I have two Dictionaries resources, and available_resources:

```
resources = {'B': 1, 's': 2, 't': 3, 'e': 3, '!': 1, 'h': 1, 'i': 1, ' ': 3, 'o': 1, 'g': 1, 'E': 1, 'A': 1, 'x': 2, 'p': 1, 'l': 1, 'r': 1}


available_resources = {'A': 1, 'l': 1, 'g': 1, 'o': 1, 'E': 1, 'x': 1, 'p': 1, 'e': 3, 'r': 1, 't': 3, ' ': 3, 'i': 1, 's': 2, 'h': 1, 'B': 1, '!': 1}
```

I want to check if resources is a subset of available_resources (if each element contained in the dictionary is <= the corresponding value entry in the resources dictionary)

I've tried:

```
    if all(available_resources.get(key, None) == val for key, val
                             in resources.items()):
          return True
```

It is returning false, is there another way I can get it to work?

Comment: protip: constructs like `if (condition): return True` almost always should be `return (condition)`

Comment: The question is worded in a confusing way. You talk about the *subset* relation (and your code seems to be trying to test that) but other parts suggest that it is a different relation that you are trying to test -- that of corresponding values being `<=`. Please clarify.

Comment: @JohnColeman My guess is that the dicts represent multisets, and the OP is talking about the "subset relation" for multisets. (Although I would also appreciate if the question was more clear!)

Answer (score 2):

Could it be a simple sign error? From "==" val to "<=" val? I got true from the below.

```py
if all(available_resources.get(key, None) <= val for key, val
                             in resources.items()):
    return True
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `>=`? (The wording of the question isn't clear, so perhaps OP is confused on the issue).

Comment: @JohnColeman  yes, you could be correct there! Currently, the question is a bit unclear. For example, what if an element exists in one but not the other. I hope the author can update with more details.

Answer (score 1):

If all the values are integers, one approach is to use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

resources = {'B': 1, 's': 2, 't': 3, 'e': 3, '!': 1, 'h': 1, 'i': 1, ' ': 3, 'o': 1, 'g': 1, 'E': 1, 'A': 1, 'x': 2, 'p': 1, 'l': 1, 'r': 1}
available_resources = {'A': 1, 'l': 1, 'g': 1, 'o': 1, 'E': 1, 'x': 1, 'p': 1, 'e': 3, 'r': 1, 't': 3, ' ': 3, 'i': 1, 's': 2, 'h': 1, 'B': 1, '!': 1}


res = bool(Counter(resources) - Counter(available_resources))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
True
```

Comment: New in version 3.10: you can compare Counter objects directly with `a <= b` rather than using `bool(b - a)`. *"Counters support rich comparison operators for equality, subset, and superset relationships: ==, !=, <, <=, >, >=. All of those tests treat missing elements as having zero counts so that Counter(a=1) == Counter(a=1, b=0) returns true.

New in version 3.10: Rich comparison operations we were added
"*

Comment: @Stef It seems at the end I was right: https://twitter.com/mesejo410/status/1201845851255123968?s=20

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<=` operator from sets. This operator determines whether one set is a subset of the other.

As follows:

```
>>> resources.items() <= available_resources.items()
False
```

This returns `False` as there is a difference between the element `x` in the different dict. You can see this difference using the set operator `^` with will return you the symmetric difference between the `dict`:

```
>>> resources.items() ^ available_resources.items()
{('x', 1), ('x', 2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<=` instead of `==`

```py
>>> all(available_resources.get(k, -1)<=v for k,v in resources.items())
True
```

Also, above method may fail if `resources` contains some key that doesn't exist in `available_resources`, and you can additionally check if the keys in resources are subset of the keys in available_resources for this condition

```py
>>> all(available_resources.get(k, -1)<=v for k,v in resources.items()) and\
        set(resources).issubset(available_resources)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the answers in this stackoverflow question: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323749/how-to-check-if-one-dictionary-is-a-subset-of-another-larger-dictionary)

And i think it's works for you!

```
all(item in available_resources.items() for item in resources.items())

# - or - # 

available_resources.items() <= resources.items()
```